# How can I make these swirling gradient spheres?

Tags: materials

Consider:

[image]

I came across this. How can I make it?

Answer (score 8):

Add noise to the input of your textures (using vector math > add).

By changing the input texture coordinates you can squash and stretch your texture along curved shapes.

[image: node setup]